# SQL Server Windows Authentication when signed in with Office 365 Azure AD

Tags: sql-server

## Environment

I have a home office with several Windows computers for testing. These computers are part of a Windows workgroup - they are not joined to a domain.

Historically, I've created a local user on each computer with the same username/password in order to share resources, such as filesystems and SQL Server. In this scenario, Windows automatically recognizes me as the "same" user (albeit with a different SID) and allows me to connect without additional prompts for credentials.

Among other things, I could use a SQL Server client on one machine to connect to a SQL Server instance on another machine via Windows Authentication.

### Recent Change

I've recently switched to **logging into Windows with my Office 365 credentials**, instead of with a local Windows user. Here's the relevant Windows Settings screen:

[image]

Now my Windows username is `AzureAD\MichaelMannion`, instead of a local name like `citra\Michael` (where "citra" is the name of the local Windows computer).

> **NOTE:** In case you're unfamiliar with this setup, it's essentially using a lightweight Azure Active Directory (AD) instance that supports my Office 365 subscription. This is not full Azure AD / AD DS. I do not have an on-prem AD instance. My machines are still just part of a workgroup, not a domain. This is *only* using the lightweight Azure AD that backs Office 365 when you log into Windows using a Microsoft "work or school" account.

The transition has been a little rocky, but I have the basics working, like sharing folders and setting file permissions with the new Office 365 AD users.

## Problem

I just built my first computer with a SQL Server instance since switching to the new Windows authentication method, and:

- **I have been unable to connect a client on one machine to SQL Server on another machine using Windows Authentication when logged into Windows with my Office 365 Azure AD credentials (i.e. "work or school" account)**

I can connect with:

- Windows Authentication when the client and server are running on the **same** computer
- SQL Server Authentication from a client on **any** computer

So, things are generally working; the problem seems to be limited to the new Azure AD style Windows credentials. Here's a screenshot using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS); note that my Windows user on the client (`AzureAD\MichaelMannion`) is not the user that SSMS is apparently using to try to connect (`NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`):

[image]

This SSMS client (18.12.1) does offer three "Azure Active Directory" authentication options:

[image]

I don't think they're relevant here, but I tried them anyway. In every case, I get a certificate error:

[image]

Neither the server (red) requires, nor client (green) requests, an encrypted connection:

[image]

[image]

So, I'm not sure which certificate the error is complaining about. This might be irrelevant anyway - from some initial reading, I think these Azure AD options may only apply to the new SQL Server 2022 Azure AD authentication feature. I'm never clear what requires "real" Azure AD and what works with "lightweight" Office 365 AD, though, so I figured I'd show these examples.

## Question

My question is:

**- Is it possible to connect SSMS on one computer to SQL Server on another computer using Windows Authentication (or an Azure AD equivalent) when logged into Windows using my Office 365 "work or school" account?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with this setting.  I'm AAD Workplace-joined but log in with a normal local account.  You should be able to add a Windows credential to the user's Credential Store to use alternate credentials for a specific network host.

Comment: I think you need Azure AD Federation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-fed in other words your domain needs to have a trust relationship with the Azure domain. This allows login. The certificate error however is caused because the machine does not trust the issuer of the SSL certificate used by SQL Server. Who issued it, is it a self-signed cert?

Comment: Shot from the dark based on past experiences, but does checking off "Trust server certificate" in the`Connection Properties` get you any further? (I would guess you should be logging in with the AAD - Integrated or AAD - Password authentication methods.)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Adding credentials for server host to Credential Store yield no change.

Comment: @Charlieface - Per the OP, there is no local domain, just a workgroup, so nothing to federate

Comment: @J.D. - Trusting server certificate yields the same 18456 error for "ANONYMOUS LOGON"

Comment: Azure Active Directory auth isn't supported in SQL Server.  You're trying always to get "Windows Authentication" working.  All the other selections are currently only valid for Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Agreed re: Windows Authentication. Windows just doesn't seem to fully support 0365 auth yet. For example, can't share directory to AzureAD\UserName with File Explorer, but can with NET SHARE /GRANT. Same with file permissions / CACLS. For whatever reason, SSMS is using anonymous instead of AzureAD\UserName. Thanks for guidance on AAD / SQL Server support, too!

Comment: Let's keep the two issues separate: the SSL issue is to do with the actual connection and is *not* a login error, you can't even connect to the server. The way to sort that is either "Trust Server Certificate" (not recommended due to security issues) or get a proper trusted certificate. Once that is sorted, you need to login. `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` just means the server's machine doesn't recognize your login token, it doesn't trust the issuer of the login token because you are not part of the same domain, it' not actually using `ANONYMOUS`. ......

Comment: .... As I said, you need to get a way for the server to trust the token, I don't think this is possible without federation using a proper AD domain. What do you get if logged in to SSMS locally on the server when you do `SELECT SUSER_SNAME()`

Comment: @Charlieface In this use case, my only concern is authentication, not connection encryption. I agree that those two issues are separate. Perhaps I shouldn't have included those examples in the OP, but the "Azure Active Directory" choices in SSMS seemed like they might be relevant; the cert error was just a by-product. Per David Browne -Microsoft, AAD auth isn't supported anyway, so I'm back to exploring Windows Authentication solutions (which don't manifest cert error). I'll clean up the OP to remove the detritus when I understand things better. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If you are in a workgroup on both machines then you can use a local Windows account with Windows Authentication, as long as the same account name and password are present on both machines. This is because it will fall back to NTLM authentication, which hashes the username and password only.

Comment: @Charlieface That's what I'm trying to do - but it doesn't seem to work when I log into Windows with my Microsoft account. Per the OP, it used to work when I was using local Windows accounts, but stopped working when I switched to using my Microsoft account. Windows 10/11 all but force you to use a Microsoft account to log in to Windows nowadays (I know how to workaround, but I've already sipped the KoolAid). The behavior, however, is neither exactly like a local Windows account, nor exactly like a real AD account. You can do some of each, but not all of either.

Comment: You could right-click SSMS and select `Run As` in other words impersonate a different local user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137943/discussion-between-manniongeo-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 0):

here are steps to get rid of the encryption and server trust error on a standalone pc -

If using a version of SQL older than 2019 then install SQL 2019 or above client tools to get the newer sql configuration manager (Otherwise you need to add the sha1 thumbprint in regedit to tell sql which cert to use.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-certificates?view=sql-server-ver16).

rename the windows pc in advanced system settings, click more on full computer name and add a dns suffix like example.com so that the full pc name becomes citra.example.com (doesn't matter if it's joined to a domain)

create a self-signed cert for citra.example.com with a private key and then use sql configuration manager to import that certificate. Finally add the certificate to your trusted root certificate store and you should not have issues with encryption or server trust.

Good luck with the authentication part